# Is it absolutely impossible to access a third-party cookie from document.cookie in the browser console?

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, geolocation, privacy

I have a simple web-page served up by an Express server (`Domain 1`). Express will return a cookie containing a `uuid` if one does not already exist on the client, which will keep track of unique users to the site (Assuming they don't switch browsers). Express also keeps track of incoming IP addresses for geo-location.

The HTML includes a `<script>` tag which requests a .js file from a separate Express server (`Domain 2`). `Domain 2` also sends a cookie containing a unique identifier.

When testing this, I could have sworn that I was able to read both cookies in `document.cookie` while browsing the page at `Domain 1`. After clearing the cookies, I can't.

Is it impossible to read third-party cookies on the first-party domain, even though they were sent TO that domain?

There are a couple of hacks that I can think of:

- I can parse the cookie from `Domain 1` and send it as a queryString to `Domain 2` in the `<script>` tag.
- I can manually send the UUID generated via the `Domain 2` cookie as a response header, and manually set the cookie through a callback function after the network request for the script resolves.

My goal is to bind both cookies together as an entity which can link the two.

Comment: Cookies are stored based on the domain in the URL that returns the cookie. It doesn't matter how the URL was requested.